# idiorm database request outside of foreach loop

Tags: php, database, idiorm

I was told that database request make in loop (foreach) is bad, but how can I do other way this request:

```
$k1 = ORM::for_table('k1')->find_many();
foreach($k1 as $k){
    $k2 = ORM::for_table('k2')->where('id', $k->id)->find_one();
    echo $k2->name;
}
```

Comment: You should use [join](http://idiorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying.html#joins) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`join`](http://idiorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying.html#joins) you can create the same query without use a loop.

Edit after the comment:

```
<?php
$results = ORM::for_table('k1')
    ->select('k2.*')
    ->join('k1_to_k2', array('k1.id', '=', 'k1_to_k2.k1_id'))
    ->join('k2', array('k1.id', '=', 'k2.id'))
    ->find_many();

foreach($results as $result){
  echo $result->name;
}
```

Previous answer:

```
<?php
$results = ORM::for_table('k1')
    ->select('k2.*')
    ->join('k2', array('k1.id', '=', 'k2.id'))
    ->find_many();

foreach($results as $result){
  echo $result->name;
}
```

Comment: And if I use 3 tables?
`$k1 = ORM::for_tabe('k1')->find_many();
foreach($k1 as $k){
    $con = ORM::for_table(k1_to_k2)->where('ki_id', $ki->id)->find_many();
    foreach($con as $item){
        $k2 = ORM::for_table('k2')->where('id', $item->k2_id)->find_one();
    }
}`

Comment: Hi @aidron if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.